# scraping and need to access elements from child window

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to access child elements of an existing web page to extract data.

First is code snippet of how the child window is opened!

```html
window[name] = window.open(url,name,'width='+wid+',height='+hgt+',left='+lt+',top='+tp+',resizable,scrollbars');
```

The code I`m trying to access info below the plus signs is what I want to extract!

```html
                 +++++
<tr onclick="submitInfo( 45815, 'test.project.noreseau');"><div name="45815"><td class="search" bgcolor="ffffff" style="cursor: pointer"><a name="45815">&nbsp;address - 6801, route Transcan, 2e</a><br>&nbsp;Autres&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  0810&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  L.B.</td></div>
```

Code I`m trying out but have no idea how to go about it!

```vb
Do
    ' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set els = oBrowser.document.getElementsByTagName("*")

For Each el In els
    Debug.Print el.ID, el.Value
Next el
```

The above Debug prints pulls out all the elements except those within the child window!

I've read that IFRAMES might be a problem but this is the only reference I found and doesn't seem to be in the affected area

```html
<iframe id="idFrame" name="isearch" frameBorder="0" marginHeight="0"  marginWidth="0" scrolling="no" src="searchFO.php?premier=oui&site=telusfo" width="100%" height="400px" onfocus="scwHide();" ></iframe>
```

Comment: A new window is not a child of the current window, so you cannot access it via that window.  Try getting a new reference to the child window: if you know the URL (or part of the URL) you can use something like the code at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541862/vba-addressing-internet-explorer-tabs/27552289#27552289

Comment: What let me to believe it was a child is when I tried to run the Debnug script to show the elements it wouldn``t show them. When I click on the page above the new window I get the sorce for that part and when I click show info for the new window section of the page  I get a different source!  I know the name of the new window!

Comment: `window.open` has the same effect as opening a new tab or browser.  did you try the code I suggested?

Comment: I`ve been toying around with the code for the last few hours and all I can do is show all the pages I have open in IE except the window I need doesn`t show up!

Comment: Sorry traveling for a while so won't be able to offer more help

Comment: I found a less complicated work around that gets me to the page directly. I didn`t think I could open the html doc within the iframe directly!